# handle escape characters in the json.loads in python?

Tags: python, json, escaping

I have a record -

input_json = `{"id": 109504954315901999, "created_at": "2022-12-13T06:29:58+00:00", "in_reply_to_id": null, "in_reply_to_account_id": null, "sensitive": false, "spoiler_text": "", "visibility": "public", "language": "de", "uri": "https://troet.cafe/users/TGamay/statuses/109504954282374823", "url": "https://troet.cafe/@TGamay/109504954282374823", "replies_count": 0, "reblogs_count": 0, "favourites_count": 0, "edited_at": null, "content": "<p>13. Dez: \"Eh? Wer bist denn Du? Willste etwa Koks haben? Das kannste vergessen. So wie Du aussiehst, hast Du auch gar keins nötig. Dein Bart ist ja noch ganz&nbsp;weiß. Hast Dir wohl grad die Markierungslinie der&nbsp;Autobahn&nbsp;reingezogen, was? Hehehe.\"<br>Dem Weihnachtsmann gefiel der&nbsp;Humor.</p>", "reblog": null, "account": {"id": 108218397610933167, "username": "TGamay", "acct": "TGamay@troet.cafe", "display_name": "TGamay", "locked": false, "bot": false, "discoverable": true, "group": false, "created_at": "2022-04-25T00:00:00+00:00", "note": "<p>Eine Perlenkette von Lichtern erschien mir. Seitdem bin ich bei Mastodon. Summa Rudis</p>", "url": "https://troet.cafe/@TGamay", "avatar": "https://files.mastodon.social/cache/accounts/avatars/108/218/397/610/933/167/original/2019387a4907e0ce.jpg", "avatar_static": "https://files.mastodon.social/cache/accounts/avatars/108/218/397/610/933/167/original/2019387a4907e0ce.jpg", "header": "https://files.mastodon.social/cache/accounts/headers/108/218/397/610/933/167/original/6ebd292535d3f7b1.jpg", "header_static": "https://files.mastodon.social/cache/accounts/headers/108/218/397/610/933/167/original/6ebd292535d3f7b1.jpg", "followers_count": 159, "following_count": 381, "statuses_count": 603, "last_status_at": "2022-12-13T00:00:00", "emojis": [], "fields": []}, "media_attachments": [], "mentions": [], "tags": [], "emojis": [], "card": null, "poll": null}`

Getting error -

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 28 (char 27)

Used below approach-

```
data = json.loads("""{}""".format(input_json))
```

Please help.

Comment: You don't seem to decode any JSON in your example. It's a Python object already.

Comment: @KlausD.  Yes its python object but when I read it in json.loads, gives me json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 28 (char 27) error

Comment: Why would you `json.loads()` a Python object? To convert it to a Python object?

Comment: I am trying to convert this input data which was first being fetched through  json.dumps and I am converting to json.loads to achive the json object , but the content key if you see in the sample data has \" , due to this its not converting to json object ? How can i handle json escape cahracters in this case?

Comment: This seems to be an x y problem. You should present your original problem since your attempted solution seems to be flawed.

Comment: Is `input_json` supposed to be a string? it will work if you treat your json as raw string: `input_json = r"""{"id": 109504954315901999, "created_at": "2022-12-13T06:29:58+00:00"..."""` and then simply `data = json.loads(input_json)`